# Terraform chaining for_each between resources

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

variables.tf

```
variable "custom_ids" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["b4d2d", "c928f140e8"]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azuread_application" "my-test-app" {
  for_each     = var.custom_ids
  display_name = "testing-application"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id , each.value ] 
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "testing-sp" {
  for_each                     = azuread_application.my-test-app
  application_id               = azuread_application.my-test-app.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id , each.value]
}
```

And the error message is:

> Error: Missing resource instance key
> Because azuread_application.my-test-app has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
> │
> │ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
> │     azuread_application.my-test-app[each.key]

Referred this : https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

What's the issue here?

**New Error:**

> │ Error: Unsupported attribute
> │
> │   on my-service-principals.tf line 24, in resource "azuread_service_principal" "testing-sp":
> │   24:   application_id               = each.value.application_id
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ each.value is a set of string
> │
> │ This value does not have any attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since chaining with `for_each` means you will be using key value pairs, you can fix this by doing the following:

```
resource "azuread_application" "my-test-app" {
  for_each     = var.custom_ids
  display_name = "testing-application"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id , each.value ]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "testing-sp" {
  for_each                     = azuread_application.my-test-app
  application_id               = each.value.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = each.value.owners
}
```

---

EDIT: since the goal of the question is different than the original post, here is how this should be set up based on the comments:

```
variable "custom_ids" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["b4d2d", "c928f140e8"]
}

resource "azuread_application" "my-test-app" {
  display_name = "testing-application"
  owners       = concat([data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id], var.custom_ids] 
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "testing-sp" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.my-test-app.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = azuread_application.my-test-app.owners
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I get a different error now. Error added to the above question.

Comment: Ok, so I have a couple of questions since you deleted the previous question similar to this one. Do you need **every** application to have owners which use the data source and each of the values from the set, or you need one list of all the owners?

Comment: Option one. Use the data source and each of the values from the set

Comment: To be more clear: All/Every application and Service Principals will have the SAME owners defined in variables.custom_ids

Comment: Does `azuread_application.my-test-app[each.key].application_id` work instead of `each.value.application_id`?

Comment: After you edited your answer from owners  = [each.value.owners] to owners                       = each.value.owners it works. But, now it is creating 2 Azure Service Principals with single user for each Service Principal. What I need is One Azure Service Principal and above two users as owners.

Comment: Well, that's what I asked in my first question. So you need the result of the data object plus two custom IDs?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confsuion

Comment: Please take a look at the edit and tell me if that's what you want/need.

Comment: Thanks! Working as expected. And sorry for the confusion